# remove a word except if it part of another word

Tags: python, pandas

i want to remove specific words except word part of anther word
here is example

```
data1 
    name    

    here is a this       
    company 
    there is no food      

data2
    words   count

    is       56
    com     17
    no      22
```

I wrote this function is working but the problem is it remove a word if if part of another word

```
def drop(y):
    for x in data2.words.values:
        y['name']= y['name'].str.replace(x, '')

    return y
```

output

```
    name

    here a th       
    pany    
    there food
```

what I expected:

```
    name    

    here a this       
    company 
    there food
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For avoid multiple spaces you can split values by space, filter out matching values and then join back:

```
s = set(data2['words'])
data1['name'] = [' '.join(y for y in x.split() if not y in s) for x in data1['name']]
print (data1)
          name
0  here a this
1      company
2   there food
```

Solution with `replace` is possible if use word boundaries `\b\b` with regex, but get multiple spaces:

```
pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in data2['words'])
data1['name'] = data1['name'].str.replace('('+ pat + ')', '')
print (data1)
           name
0  here  a this
1       company
2  there   food
```

So last is necessary remove them:

```
pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in data2['words'])
data1['name'] = data1['name'].str.replace('('+ pat + ')', '').str.replace(' +', ' ')
print (data1)
          name
0  here a this
1      company
2   there food
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not separating your sentence into words. Therefore, also word fragments are replaced. This should work:

```
def drop(y):
    for x in data2.words.values:
        y['name'] = " ".join([entry.replace(x, '') for entry in y['name'].split()])

    return y
```

Answer (score 1):

here is the solution which can solve your problem you need to separate the sentence before replacing the value else it will consider that as a single word and replaces values.

```
 data1 = pd.DataFrame(data = {"name":["here is a this company there is no food"]})
 data2 = pd.DataFrame(data = {"words": ["is", "com", "no"]})

 def drop(data1,data2):
     for i in df2["words"]:
         data['name'] = " ".join([j.replace(i, '') for j in data1['name'].split()])

     return data
```